# ForEach to convert all string to upper case

Tags: foreach, java-8

Looking at this code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class LmadaExperiment {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<String> li = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three");

        li.forEach(element -> element.toUpperCase());

        li.forEach(System.out::print);

    }
}
```

Guess what is the answer of this ?

Answer: Its not converted to uppercase.

Anyone knows why ?

Comment: You *are* converting each string. And then ignoring the result. You want to use `replaceAll` instead. `li.replaceAll(element -> element.toUpperCase());` or `li.replaceAll(String::toUpperCase);`

Answer (score 2):

The function toUpperCase returns the string, so you need to set `element = element.toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` won’t use `element` as a reference. You’re not actually manipulating the `element`, just it’s representation.

You could either use a `map`, to actually manipulate the array, or `System.out.print` each element `toUpperCase`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LmadaExperiment {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<String> li = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three");

        List<String> li_uc= li.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).collect(Collectors.asList());

        li_uc.forEach(System.out::print);

    }
}
```

Comment: I can’t actually test it, but I don’t think that even if you do “li.forEach(element -> element = element.toUpperCase());” it will give you the desired result.